# DNN hosted website again showing installation page

Tags: dotnetnuke, web-hosting

I have created my Dot Net Nuke website in my local machine with WebMetrix. Then uploaded all the files to server by using filezila. But while taking the site it is again showing the installation page.

What could be the possible reason? Shall i need to change any settings in Web. config. Helps are very much appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Facebook.

Comment: Did you upload your database?

Comment: yes i have uploaded db

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it still showed the install screen again after you imported the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it would show the installation is because it doesn't know there is a DB, and is trying to install again. You'll need to be sure that SQL Server express is installed on your webserver as well if you want to use the MDF file in the app_data folder.

Comment: i have copied data from local db to server by Export Data feature of SQL server. But still  it have the same issue

Comment: You really should backup/restore the database, and then modify the web.config to point to the SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

When Using the newer versions of dnn most everything is stored in the sql... Make sure to import that also!